# Reference-request: original formulation of Erdős discrepancy problem.

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory

It is often claimed that Erdős discrepancy conjecture was formulated by him in 1932. In [Tao's proof of the conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.05363) he says the original formulation is

> Every sequence $f(1),f(2),\ldots$ taking values in $\{-1,+1\}$ has infinite discrepancy.

Tao defines discrepancy as $$\sup_{k,n\in\mathbb{N}}\lvert\sum_{j=1}^kf(jn)\rvert$$

I am looking for the original formulation if it exists and hopefully some of his motivations for it. I have found two publications by Erdős in 1932 but both are in Hungarian and they seem to be proofs rather than problem statements.
[Here](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1932-01.pdf) and [here](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1932-02.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erdős writes in [1957](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1957-13.pdf) that he made the conjecture "Twenty-five years ago". So that's at least a reference by himself, but unfortunately not the desired original publication. As he doesn't seem to give a reference to such a publication there, I am beginning to suspect that the original conjecture might have been spread by "personal communication".

Comment: I sort of assumed that was the case. Very interesting however to find some formulation of his together with an approximate date!